# Why is sigmoid function used to determine posterior probability?

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a neural network in Java. I came across this in my machine learning textbook, while studying neural networks:

To give some background, the section was talking about using a single perceptron for classification. The perceptron computes a simple function that is a a weighted sum of the inputs. Lets call the output of this function f(x). The sigmoid function then takes in f(x) as input. Here's the sentence in the textbook:

```
The output of the sigmoid function may be interpreted as the posterior 
probability that the input x belongs to a certain class.
```

Why does the output of the sigmoid function be interpreted as the probability that the input belongs to a certain class?

Comment: the output value range of sigmoid function is (0,1], so may be interpreted as the posterior probability that the input x belongs to a certain class

Comment: Why sigmoid function though? Many other functions have a range of (0,1].

Comment: yes, other functions have a range of (0,1] is ok too

Comment: So you're saying that any function that has a range (0,1] would be a measure of probability that the classification is correct? I don't see how that can be true.

Comment: @Crikckter any function that has a range (0,1] can be but may not be good, sigmoid have some features make it better in many applications.

Comment: Well, so my question is.. what are those features?

Comment: lennon has metioned in the answer， Andrew ng proveed in general linear model，when assumes a binomial probability model for the outcome，the function should be sigmoid

Comment: I believe the answer is related to the sigmoid describing a c.d.f (cumulative distribution function), if we take the connection weights to be *log* probabilities, or more specifically log probability ratios. e.g. weight = log(P(o|x)/P(!o|x)). If you now do the standard multiply by weights and sum, then you're basically calculating the probability function of a binary output variable. Sorry, can't say much more than that, I'm trying to find the answer myself!

Answer (score 2):

In neural network, the sigmoid activation function at output layer somehow borrows logistic regression (in which standard sigmoid function is often used) in the classification problem. This assumes a binomial probability model for the outcome. Under this assumption, the logistic regression model is maximum likelihood that quantifies the relative changes on X in the risk of the outcome Y difference in the predictor. The loss function of logistic regression model is also related to the likelihood.

There are more discussions on [the relationship between neural network and logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43538/difference-between-logistic-regression-and-neural-networks). Also note that sigmoid usually refers to the shape (and limits), [tanh is a also sigmoid function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847133/neural-activation-functions-difference-between-logistic-tanh-etc).

Answer (score 1):

If the output of your network is sigmoid(w.x), this forces the output into the interval [0-1]. So it's at least a candidate for a probability. Furthermore, if the loss function on your network is cross-entropy loss instead of squared-error loss (which is a very appealing loss function if you want to interpret your network's output as a probability), the partial derivative of the weight w.r.t. the loss function are very simple, which means it's easy to optimise too.

Incidentally, a no-hidden-layers neural net with sigmoid output trained to minimise cross entropy loss *is* logistic regression.